# Can't delete NSG rule through powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to create a Runbook to delete any addition to a specific NSG group through a Azure Automation runbook.

In order to do so, I have the following script:

```
$nsg_item = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name  $NSG -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
Write-Output ("NSG content before removal: " + $nsg_item)
Remove-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $rule -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg_item
```

When I do so, the runbook is executed with no issues and the output from the script shows that the rule has been removed 
from the NSG.

Before:

> SecurityRules            : {Port_443, default-allow-ssh, Port_8080

After:

> SecurityRules            : {Port_443, default-allow-ssh}

However, if I then go on the relevant NSG, the rule is still present and enabled. I tried to run the same script through the Powershell CLI in Azure and the same thing occurs.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pipe the result to the `Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup` cmdlet:

```
Remove-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $rule -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg_item | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
```